# How can I get instant updates about missed bakes and endorsements using RPC API?

Tags: rpc, api, missed-endorsement

I'm new to Tezos and I'm searching for a couple of dev tips for my project. I'm creating a scanner which is able to detect missed bakes and endorsements for a specific delegate, which is a kind of variable in config (say, tz1e9ZH87proooFwLidjvE8fhusWfeDf3bgk). I already have a tezos mainnet node with tezos shell and tezos client inside it.

P.S. I know about nofitier bot in telegram, but it is using the tzkt api and sometimes fails to report missed bakes and endorsements. That's why I'm searching for some tips regarding vanilla RPC API.

Comment: The fact that the bot uses TzKT API has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that the bot fails sometimes. Please, don't mislead people.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. there might be just problems with the bot itself. but stiil, it does not actually save us from the fact that pipeline might some time fail on the tzkt api side. so i decided to do my own. to some extent, it's reinventing the wheel with the purpose to get to know tezos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple actually. What you do is get the baking (and endorsing) rights for the current block, wait until the block is baked, then simply check if all the endorsements are present, and if the block was baked at prio > 0. All of this can be done with 3 vanilla RPC calls: baking_rights, endorsing_rights, fetch block (/chains/main/block/)

You don't even need tezos-client since all RPC calls are just http/https, any major programming language has native functionality here. You don't even really need your own node; any public RPC will work here too.